# ts-node ignore custom type declaration

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, ts-node

Problem is as the topic states it. Interesting thing - i have another project with a very similar config and types working well there.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "untitled",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "ts-node test.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^12.0.4",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jszip": "^3.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.1"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es6",
         "dom"
      ],
      "typeRoots" : [
         "./node_modules/@types",
         "."
      ],
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": false
   },
   "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "**/*.spec.ts",
      "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

***index.d.ts***

```
declare interface Array<T> {
    random() :T;
}

declare namespace NodeJS {
    export interface Global {
        __stack: any;
        __line: any;
        __function: any;
        sleep: Function;
    }
}
```

It's a simple project for test purposes - `index.d.ts` located in project's root dir(tried to move `index.d.ts` -> `typings/index.d.ts`) as well (surely `tsconfig.json` too with new paths).

every attempt ends up with

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
polyfills.ts:1:17 - error TS2339: Property 'random' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
```

***polyfills.ts***

```
Array.prototype.random = function () {
    return this[Math.floor((Math.random()*this.length))];
};
```

these errors.
Please help :)

**Update:**

`tsc && node build/test.js` is working properly

Comment: The example that you posted in the question does not produce an error. Is there supposed to be an additional file such as `test.ts`?

Comment: Since the error is in polyfills.ts you should include that code in your question

Comment: the only relevant info in `test.ts` is a `import './polyfills';` being a first string.
`polyfills` itself is not relevant to prob - it's not working because the definitions are not found.